# how to get key of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#some dictionary data{}
data = {1:[3,1,4,2,6]}
```

How to print the key of data i.e

```
print( key_of(data) ) #print in some ways.
```

output:

> 1

What I got till now is to use `data.keys()` function but whenever I use that function output will be like:

> dict_keys([1])

So, what is the problem with that function. Can any one suggest me the answer.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```
print(list(data))
```

to print all the keys. If you want to print a specific key then you'll have to search for it:

```
print(next(key for key, value in data.items() if value == something))
```

Note that there is *no* guarantee on the order of the keys.

```
>>> data = {'a': 1, 'aa': 2, 'b': 3, 'cd': 4}
>>> list(data)
['cd', 'a', 'b', 'aa']
>>> data['f'] = 1
>>> list(data)
['cd', 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'f']
>>> del data['a']
>>> list(data)
['cd', 'b', 'aa', 'f']
>>> data[1] = 1
>>> list(data)
['cd', 1, 'b', 'aa', 'f']
>>> for c in ('cde', 'fgh', 'ijk', 'rmn'):
...     data[c] = 1
... 
>>> list(data)
[1, 'aa', 'cde', 'cd', 'rmn', 'b', 'ijk', 'fgh', 'f']
```

Note how the keys do *not* follow alphabetical order, and how inserted keys aren't always appended to the list of keys. Also after some insertions some key were swapped. Removing/inserting keys can change the order in unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 2):

There's no issue with `dict.keys`, it returns a view like object in Python3. You can use `list()` on the dict to get a list of keys.

```
>>> data = {1:[3,1,4,2,6]}
>>> keys = list(data)
>>> keys
[1]
>>> keys[0]
1
```

**Note:** If dict contains more than one keys then the order can be arbitrary and `keys[0]` can return any key.

```
>>> dic = {'a12': 1, 'sd':'sdfd', 'sdfsd': 'sdfsd'}
>>> list(dic)               #Arbitrarily ordered
['sdfsd', 'sd', 'a12']
```